# about garbage collector when deleting a node from LinkedList

Tags: java, garbage-collection, linked-list

this is a sample code from delete function in my LinkedList class which deletes a node from middle.

```
        temp.getPrev().setNext(temp.getNext());
        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
        temp.setNext(null);
        temp.setPrev(null);
```

my question is do i have to set temps next and prev references to null or does garbage collector handle with this automatically_?. i will appreciated very much if you can help me. and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Garbage Collector analyze if there is any reference **to** an object. Since there is no reference to `temp` after your method is finished, GC should remove this object.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector will see when there's no references left **to** `temp`. Therefore you don't have to care about nulling outgoing references - if you can't reach temp anymore it will be garbage collected (eventually).

Comment: so garbage collector collects temp immediately after the second line which is temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());

Comment: No, you will need to set `temp=null` (otherwise you do have a reference to temp - temp itself!). Also, garbage collection is not done in a deterministic fashion. You simply can't know exactly when it will run, just that when it runs it will delete all unreachable objects.

Comment: what do you mean that temp have a reference to itself_?. could you explain_?

Comment: If temp is a local variable in a method, there's no need to set it to null.  The reference will be gone when you exit the method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should. The node is no longer referenced anywhere, so even though it references valid objects, it will be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that there are no live references to temp. You don't need to do anything extra.

Answer (score 1):

The GC only takes references to an object in consideration. It does not matter if the object has references to other objects.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is do i have to set temps next and prev references to null or does garbage collector handle with this automatically_?

You do not have to set references in an object's fields to null before it becomes unreachable.

Nor will the garbage collector set them to null for you.

But a reference to an object from an unreachable object does not prevent garbage collection.

So if later on the only references to the next (or previous) node are from other unreachable nodes, then that node can be collected.